# monacaで設置されているグーグルマップアプリを開く方法

Tags: javascript, monaca, jquery, html5, cordova

monacaでアンドロイドとIOS両方を支援するハイブリッドアプリを開発しています。
リンクを押すと現在地と目的地の座標を渡して設置されているグーグルマップが開かれるようにし、渡された座標でグーグルマップのナビが実行されるようにしたいんです。
現在は

```
window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + start
  + '&daddr=' + end + '&directionsmode=driving', '_system');
```

このようなコードを使っています。アンドロイドではリンクを押して上のコードが動くと、インタネットで繋ぐか設置されているグーグルマップアプリにつなぐか聞くダイアログが表示されます。でも、IOSはすぐsafariを利用してグーグルマップを繋げてしまい、困っています。
アンドロイドもIOSも設置されているグーグルマップが開かれるようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

iOSの場合`http://`ではなく`comgooglemaps://`を使うとgooglemapsアプリで開けます。Googleの公式ドキュメントをご参考に。
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

ただ、これだとAndroidでうまく開けないので、`monaca.isIOS()`なり`monaca.isAndroid()`を利用して処理を分岐することになると思います。